# MSP430F5438 SD card using an SPI interface

Tags: sd-card, spi, msp430, adc

I want to connect an SD card using the SPI interface of [MSP430F5438](http://www.ti.com/product/msp430f5438). The hardware part is correct in my design, however I could not send any data to the SD card. The source code I use is from *[Secure Digital Card Interface for the MSP430](http://alumni.cs.ucr.edu/~amitra/sdcard/Additional/sdcard_appnote_foust.pdf)*.

For debugging, how could I send data to the SD card? The data should be received from the ADC12MEM registers and just need to be written in the SD card. From this source code above, there is no process, when I debug and I could not send any user input to the SD card.

Comment: Is your SD card bigger than 2 GB?

Comment: yes, my sd card is 8GB.
When I have debug the code, I have seen that it stucks at f_mount function where the disk is initialized and mounted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the linked PDF works only for SD cards <= 2 GB and not for SDHC cards (4 GB and bigger). If you can not find such a small card as full size SD, just use a microSD with an adapter - they are electrically the same.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Besides, did you work on Elm Chan's FatFs? I also work on that for 8 GB SD card and many people say that it supports over 4GB. I have examined FatFs and wrote my own SPI on Elm Chan's FS, however I am stuck at one point. If you're familiar with that, I could ask a question. Thanks.

Comment: SDHC needs support both on the fileystem layer - FAT32 - and on the "SPI" layer. Initialization and block read/write is different for SDHC.

Comment: I have tried the source code for 1GB SD card and still I get the error " sd card is not in idle state " . So the initialization is not complete. It is a generic code and I set the pins for my msp430f5438 from TI's example codes. I still cannot get any answer from the SD.
I do not know where to check or where to fix, would you please help me to find a solution to this problem?