# Maximum size SD card using SPI protocol

Tags: microcontroller, sd-card, spi

Good morning,
for my project I would need to interface a microcontroller with a SD card that is 128 GB or more.
I've read on internet that in order to communicate with a SD card I can use SD protocol or SPI protocol. On my microcontroller I have SPI available and therefore I would need to go for that way.
I've found a lot of information on internet. The post [MSP430F5438 SD card using an SPI interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984024/msp430f5438-sd-card-using-an-spi-interface) was very helpful to understand how to interface the micro with the SD. But, based on my understanding, the maximum size of a SD card using SPI protocol seems to be limited to 2GB. Is that true or I can use any dimension I need? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The address you use is a block address, not a byte address. If you change the block size to something big enough (bigger than the usual 512 bytes per block), you should be able to access the whole memory.